# VBA Excel PDF output not good on page

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

Im trying to print some pdf's for each filter from row A. But i see just 3 columns in each page of the pdf. I want column A-K all on 1 page. How can i reach it? I want each output PDF as 1 page. I used this VBA Excel Code:

```
Sub Copy_To_Workbooks()

Dim My_Range As Range
Dim FieldNum As Long
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim foldername As String
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim CCount As Long
Dim WSNew As Worksheet
Dim ErrNum As Long

'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
Set My_Range = Range("A1:K" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
My_Range.Parent.Select

If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
   My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
           vbOKOnly, "Copy to new workbook"
    Exit Sub
End If

'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
FieldNum = 1

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

'Set the file extension/format
If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    'You use Excel 97-2003
    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
Else
    'You use Excel 2007-2013
    If ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat = 56 Then
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
    Else
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
    End If
End If

'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False



'Delete the sheet RDBLogSheet if it exists
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("RDBLogSheet").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0

' Add worksheet to copy/Paste the unique list
Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
ws2.Name = "RDBLogSheet"

'Fill in the path\folder where you want the new folder with the files
'you can use also this "C:\Users\Ron\test"
MyPath = Application.DefaultFilePath

'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If

'Create folder for the new files
foldername = MyPath & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & "\"
MkDir foldername

With ws2
    'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
    My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=.Range("A3"), Unique:=True

    'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
    Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("A4:A" & Lrow)

        'Filter the range
        My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
         Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

        'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
        CCount = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                 .Areas(1).Cells.Count
        On Error GoTo 0
        If CCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                 & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                 & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                   vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
        Else
            'Add new workbook with one sheet
            Set WSNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

            'Copy/paste the visible data to the new workbook
            My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            With WSNew.Range("A1")
                ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                .Select
            End With

            'Save the file in the new folder and close it

            On Error Resume Next

WSNew.Parent.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=foldername & cell.Value & "_2017_03_Kostenspecificiatie OV", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False

            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                ErrNum = ErrNum + 1

                WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                 "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum

                .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & _
                  "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr & """)"

                .Cells(cell.Row, "A").Interior.Color = vbRed
            Else
                .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = _
                "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & cell.Value & FileExtStr & """)"
            End If

            WSNew.Parent.Close False
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If

        'Show all the data in the range
        My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

    Next cell
    .Cells(1, "A").Value = "Red cell: can't use the Unique name as file name"
    .Cells(1, "B").Value = "Created Files (Click on the link to open a file)"
    .Cells(3, "A").Value = "Unique Values"
    .Cells(3, "B").Value = "Full Path and File name"
    .Cells(3, "A").Font.Bold = True
    .Cells(3, "B").Font.Bold = True
    .Columns("A:B").AutoFit

End With

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

If ErrNum > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
         & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
         & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
End If

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
My_Range.Parent.Select
ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
ws2.Select
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Edit:
This code added and it works now:

```
 With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Zoom = 45
 End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your issue is that you have not defined the print area properly.

I had similar issues and figured out the following:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
  .Orientation = xlPortrait
  .PrintArea = "$A$1:$L$47" 'Change this to your print area.
  .Zoom = False
  .FitToPagesTall = False
  .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
  Type:=xlTypePDF, _
  Filename:=your_file_name_here, _
  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
  From:=1, _
  To:=3, _      'This line is optional if you have multiple pages
  OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Hope this helps..